# How can I Log In user automatically after checking comparing user.email_verification_token?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My idea is to call LoginUser after checking **user.email_verification_token == token** and pass user's email and password, but there is a problem because I don't how to pass them as instance of django.http.HttpRequest.

Could you help me guys?

```
    @api_view(['POST'])
def verify_email(request, pk, token):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

    if user.expiration_date < timezone.now():
        return AuthenticationFailed('expired_token')

    if user.email_verification_token == token:
        user.is_email_verified = True
        user.save()

        return Response('message: success')
    return Response('message: Verification Rejected')


    @api_view(['POST'])
def LoginUser(request):
    email = request.data['email']
    password = request.data['password']

    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

    if user is None:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

    if not user.check_password(password):
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')
     ........
     ........
```

Comment: Where would you be getting the user's email and password? Would the user have to submit it?

Comment: Each route in Django should correspond to a single function for better organization, easier debugging and testing. If you are creating an API route that checks emails, it should only check emails, not log in users.